# BizTalk schema generation for a transaction with multiple records with only one tag

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a data file containing following transaction records

```
1020915  
2Suppliers - Non Consumption  
2Offer sheet needed  
3CRIV SOL  
43005t5677 

1021015  
2Shippment to New York  
3Be required to provide receipts when turning in sheets   
(Invoice was not sent in time. Copy was requested)  
43005yg876
```

Each line of record starts with tag identifier 1,2,3,4. My problem is the second transaction with tag of 3. Notice that no tag appears in the line (Invoice was not sent in time. Copy was requested). In fact it is a new line with 'LF' in the end of previous line. How to make a schema to capture this anomaly?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512862/biztalk-flatfile-schema-multiple-irregular-repeating-records/34596495#34596495 (also asked by you)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't because the Disassembler would have no way to know if the errant CR/LF is the record delimiter or actual content.

Your problem is that the file is invalid, it's not BizTalk or your schema or anything on your end.

So, the first thing you need to do is let the supplier of this file know that they're sending invalid content.

If then cannot or will not correct their problem, the second thing you do is inform your management that, because they are producing invalid data, you have to spend extra time fixing it.

Finally, you'd have to write a Pipeline Component for the Decode state that attempted to detect invalid CR/LF's and replace them.  Note, this can get very tricky because you still won't know if [CR/LF]3 is a delimiter or content.

Good luck!

Comment: The line with tag 3 is a description field. Some users hit Enter key to start a new line of content even though they don't need to as it automatically wrap the text.

Comment: Yes, and that's perfectly fine for the user but it doesn't really matter why it happens.  Who eve is producing this file is still making an unparsable file because of the ambiguous CR/LF.  They need to fix this on their end.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you'd want to write a custom disassembler.  There might be a way to trick FFDASM to handle this right, but it's a pretty simple message and wouldn't be hard.  There's a tutorial on that on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35046/Custom-BizTalk-Pipeline-Disassembler-Component).

Your disassemble method might look something like:

```cs
msgPart = pInMsg.BodyPart;
Stream originalStream = pInMsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(originalStream);
XNamespace ns = "http://schema_name_space";
XDocument returnDoc = new XDocument(new XElement(ns + "SchemaRootNode"));

while (reader.Peek() > -1)
{
   // use reader.ReadLine() to consume your lines, use the first character to determine what kind of node to put them into
   xd.Root.Add( // new XElement with your string in it based on the "tag"
                // with logic to determine whether line has a tag or not.
}

VirtualStream vts = new VirtualStream();
xd.Save(vts);
vts.Position = 0;

IBaseMessage outMsg = pInMsg;
outMsg.BodyPart.Data = vts;

pContext.ResourceTracker.AddResource(vts);
pContext.ResourceTrakcer.AddResource(reader); // BizTalk will dispose of these later

outMsg.Context.Promote("MessageType", 
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties",
  "http://schema_name_space#SchemaRootNode");
outMsg.Context.Promote("SchemaStrongName", 
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/system-properties",
  "SchemaAssembly full name");

qOutputMsgs.Enqueue(outMsg);
```